# Can boosting be thought of as a genetic algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning

Can boosting be classified as a genetic algorithm or as an instance of simulated annealing?

Or, is it a completely different paradigm?

Essentially, I'm trying to rectify discrete optimization methods with their counter parts in machine learning.

Thanks!

Also, if you can provide a reference, that'd be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a completely different paradigm.  Boosting involves using a group of outcomes to achieve a final result instead of just one. The outcomes are separately weighted so that more accurate ones have a bigger influence on the final result.  It is hard to understand simulated annealing starting from simulated annealing. I recommend looking at articles on MCMC first, or understand the idea of hill-climbing (iteratively moving to the next best solution). GAs are once again different, but the most intuitive, since they are pretty true to their name.

Comment: Okay, got it. And yeah, I'm familiar with MCMC, but since the algorithms accomplish similar tasks and do aggregate local solutions, I was wondering one can be rephrased in terms of the others. But, now I see the subtleties.